Optimising a DynamoDB table for MES production items
I'm designing a new AppSync model for a Manufacturing Executing System and one of the most important access patterns is "Get all items in a given production date interval" and "Get all items in location X in a given production date interval", more specifically for a calendar/planning view (with date range).
type Project @model {
 id: ID!
 name: String
 items: [Item] @hasMany
}

type Item @model {
 id: ID!
 ref: String
 projectID: ID
 location: String
 productionDate: AWSDate
}


I've been trying different composite pk/sk keys and indexes but mostly my problem relies on the high frequency that an item can change its production date or location, making it harder to be a pk or sk (maybe I'm wrong here?).
One idea that occurred to me was to delete the item and rewrite it every time the productionDate or location changed, that way I would be able to keep similar production dates together (using a partition key, also items with productionDate < today will be less accessible as intended)
Is there a way to design this model to make these access patterns more efficient and avoid scans?
For context, I'm using AWS amplify for this prototype

You want to obtain all items based on a location and date?
SELECT * FROM TABLE WHERE Date BETWEEN x AND y ?

@LeeroyHannigan yes that would be the end result. But I want to avoid a scan (getting all items and filter them after)

I'll write my answer below.

Wanting to do a request based on time can be tricky in DynamoDB. One way to do it is to use a GSI where you place a static value as partition key, and date as the sort key:



GSIPK
GSISK
Data




1
2022-03-05T12:00:000Z
some data


1
2023-02-06T13:00:000Z
some data


1
2024-03-07T14:00:000Z
some data


1
2024-04-08T15:00:000Z
some data



Now when you do a Query for all of the items since Jan 2024:
SELECT * FROM myTable.myGsi WHERE GSIPK=1 AND GSISK BETWEEN '2024-01-01T00:00:000Z' AND '2024-04-10T14:00:000Z'
That is now efficient. There are some caveats to this design, and I explain it all in detail in this blog post.

Thanks for the quick reply and this great blog post. I'll study now what it would take to max the partition limit (how likely is it) and how costly it would be to then retrieve this data (while using partition sharding).
